# Custom URL from a checkbox form

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a custom URL from some checkboxes.

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
    <input type="checkbox" name="q" value="label:TAG1" />TAG1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="q" value="label:TAG2" />TAG2<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="q" value="label:TAG3" />TAG3<br />
    <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" />
</form>
```

I have this: `http://www.exemple.com/search?q=label:TAG1&q=label:TAG2&q=label:TAG3`

But I want this: `http://www.exemple.com/search/?q=label:TAG1|label:TAG2|label:TAG3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:
*(explanations are within the code)*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").on("submit",function(e){
        // Disable the button's submit.
        e.preventDefault();

        // Start setting a custon query.
        var query="?q=";

        // Check each checked checkboxes.
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index){
            // Adds | only on second and next...
            if(index>0){
                query+="|";
            }
            // Adds the value.
            query+=$(this).val();
        });
        //Redirect with the query in GET
        console.log( $(this).attr("action")+query );
        window.location=$(this).attr("action")+query;
    });
});
```

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/XjvpjL?editors=1011)

**EDIT**

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I really appreciated it! But it is not working on my blog. I'm still getting this: http://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/search?q=label%3ATAG1&q=label%3ATAG2&q=label%3ATAG3 

(It is working on codepen, but I don't know why it's not working on my blog)

Comment: You have `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)` in console... Meaning that jQuery isn't loaded.

Comment: Oh no! I apologize for that. I am still learning how to get there. I added the ajax libs to my blog. What am I missing?

Comment: Hit [F12] to see the console... Now you have fixed the jQuery error. Great. You still have `https://mirocine.googlecode.com/files/paginacionbloggermtb.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()` This file is not found. Maybe a path error ?

Comment: I already fixed that error. But I still don't know why the jquery is not working. :(

Comment: Hew... Strange. Try changing `<input type="submit" value="Filtrar" />` for `<input type="button" id="filter" value="Filtrar" />` and `$("form").on("submit",function(e){` for `$("form").on("click","#filter",function(e){`

Comment: Now you have a quote issue on line #596. `$('input[type='checkbox']:checked').each(function(index){` Use double-quotes outer and single inner.

Comment: Haa... I just saw it. The script I gave you is in the `<head>`!! Wrap it with `$(document).ready(){function(){` before... And `});` after. Use the original script I gave you.

Comment: I fixed that too. I'll try changing the attributes.

Comment: I got another error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: `$(document).ready(){function(){` ==> remove `)` ==> `$(document).ready({function(){`

Comment: I tried to do what you said: "Try changing <input type="submit" value="Filtrar" /> for <input type="button" id="filter" value="Filtrar" /> and $("form").on("submit",function(e){ for $("form").on("click","#filter",function(e){"

But everything stop working.

Comment: I did that too! But still not working! Hope I'm not bothering you. :(

Comment: ok... Remove the extra `{`... Sorry, I din't see it in my last comment. I edited my answer. Syntax is important. ==> `$(document).ready(function(){`