# How to use localStorage to save radio and display all the items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

I have this blog (https://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/?m=2) I am developing.

This is the body code: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/DonnyBrooker/pen/LbPqva)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {

    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("wrong")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
    
    $(this).prop('checked', true);

    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
    $(this).parent()
    .addClass("right")
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");
    
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);
  });

  $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    //$(this).parent()
    //.siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    if( $(this).prop("checked") == true) {
 return false;
    } else {
    
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").parent()
    .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


.option {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  background-image:url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-5zENhyIEpxk/WBlziC5KHEI/AAAAAAAACcw/UEZqzY0EA4cOqEgzJyHvaXrOZCm7b_oZQCLcB/s1600/circle-1.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position:10px 50%;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 35px ;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -khtml-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  //margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}

.option:hover {
  background-color:#eeeeee;
  background-image:url(https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Fby5eMbgJsE/WBopfcqsk1I/AAAAAAAACes/1TIz_GeHcvMdOX1dflzd6aHmOJ8ZwhP1ACLcB/s1600/circle.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position:10px 50%;
  color: #000;
}

input[type=&quot;radio&quot;] {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.right, .right:hover {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  background-image:url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-PHpDpRx1uQk/WBl5t-tKDaI/AAAAAAAACdc/pCRHItQM0ZokCupwqvURZll2TwJ9CcIaACLcB/s1600/checked-symbol.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position:10px 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrong, .wrong:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  background-image:url(https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-aiETYepUTDs/WBl5t32FrTI/AAAAAAAACdg/dppZ49C9vV4eJoQU3l_C7xUm0Am5UQMywCLcB/s1600/cross-mark-on-a-black-circle-background.png);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-position:10px 50%;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form3">
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  <br /><br />
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />

</form>


<form class="form3">
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  <br /><br />
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
</form>


<form class="form3">
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="slider"></div>
</label>
  <br /><br />
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option1">A</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option2">B</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option3">C</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="wrong" class="option4">D</label>
    <label class="option"><input type="radio" name="option" value="right" class="option5">E</label>
    <br />
</form>
```

How can I use localStorage to save the options people choose (item for the "first hit", item for the "last hit", item for the title, item for the link from the post not from the window)? And how can I display the "first hit" as a link in the sidebar? Something like this:

```
<a class="wrong" href="https://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/2016/11/141602112016.html">Q141602112016</a>

<a class="right" href="https://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/2014/10/042408102014.html">Q042408102014</a>
```

I know it is such a complex project, but I want some tips to start because I am finding it hard to implement.

Some exemples:
[localStorage of Radio Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18305804/localstorage-of-radio-button?rq=1)
http://jsfiddle.net/TzPW9/315/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your HTML, only added ids to each of your forms.

In JS, I added functions to set, clear and retreive locally stored infos.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[value='wrong']").click(function() {
        $(this).parent()
            .addClass("wrong")
            .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);

        // Added this
        var form_id=$(this).closest('form').attr("id");
        var selection_class = $(this).attr("class");
        SaveSelection(form_id,selection_class);
    });

    $("input[value='right']").click(function() {
        $(this).parent()
            .addClass("right")
            .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

        $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', true);

        // Added this
        var form_id=$(this).closest('form').attr("id");
        var selection_class = $(this).attr("class");
        SaveSelection(form_id,selection_class);
    });

    $("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        //$(this).parent()
        //.siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

        if( $(this).prop("checked") == true) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").parent()
                .siblings().removeClass("right wrong");

            $(this).closest('form').find("input[type='radio']").prop('checked', false);

            // Added this
            var form_id = $(this).closest('form').attr("id");
            clearSelection(form_id);
        }
    });

    // Set a form's localStorage
    function SaveSelection(form_id,selection_class){
        console.log("Answered "+selection_class+" in form: "+form_id );
        localStorage.setItem(form_id, selection_class);
    }

    // Clear a form's localStorage
    function clearSelection(form_id){
        console.log("Clearing answer in form: "+form_id );
        localStorage.setItem(form_id, "");
    }

    // If some localStorage exist
    var form_amount = $("form").length;
    for(i=0;i<form_amount;i++){
        var stored = localStorage.getItem( $("form").eq(i).attr("id") );
        if( stored ){
            console.log("Retreiving answer for "+$("form").eq(i).attr("id")+" and simulate a click.");
            //console.log( $("form").eq(i).find("."+stored) );
            $("form").eq(i).find("."+stored).click();
        }
    }
});
```

See in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oYNxeP?editors=1011)

Feel free to ask if you need explanations...
;)

Comment: Thank you so much! Hopefully, I did't need to rebuild my whole concept.

Comment: You helped me with the checkbox custom URL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40367527/custom-url-from-a-checkbox-form). But now, it stoped working after I made the additions. Do you know why? :/

Comment: mmm... The previous question was redirecting the page + a GET value to it based on the checkboxes values... I dont see checkbox values here. Can you start a codePen with what you have now ?

Comment: Thank you so much! I put everything here (http://codepen.io/DonnyBrooker/pen/BQaLZP). I don't wanna bother you with that, but do you think it is possible to get this result (http://jsfiddle.net/JFlo/689rA/) +plus localStorage to keep on the checkboxes of the filter? God bless you!!!

Comment: Ok... I only changed `.size()` for `.length` two places... And I added `form3` in the brand new function here `$("form3 input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {` so it won't interfer with the form2 checkboxes. ;) [**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/JbjRaN?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciated it!!! If you want to see the final result on my blog, feel free and hit the following link: https://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/?m=2

Comment: That's nice work! ;) I'm not very good at spanish... But the layout is clean.

Comment: Thanks! After all, you deserve all the credit! Oh, and that is Portuguese from Brazil! *---*

Comment: I just noticed something... I tried the Google translate extention of my browser. It seems like your use of `<label>` is problematic. I would try to replace them by `<div>` instead. [See this printscreen](http://i1208.photobucket.com/albums/cc370/Bes7weB/temp-xyz_zpscuarguj9.png)

Comment: Oh no! That looks bad! It's crazy how CSS, HTML and JS change around. I tried to replace labels by divs, but the radios are not being selected on div/span/text click. Maybe the right use of `<label>` is `<input type="radio" id="rad" name="radio"/>
<label for="rad">A Label</label>`. And also I found this http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/4xK86/

Comment: Please could you help me fix the js code? http://codepen.io/DonnyBrooker/pen/pNoOZM

Comment: I think I fixed it. In CodePen, I can't try the "translation extention"... We'll see if it really fixes the problem when you update your blog with the code in [**this CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zoYmEd). Notice the new CSS class `.hiddenRadio` and the new function `$(".option").click(function(){...`

Comment: Hey... I think I got it! Please could you take a look at my blog and see if that problem keeps happening?  (https://simulatorio.blogspot.com.br/?m=2)

Comment: I messed it all up!!! hahahah... I'll update my blog with your code! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127403/discussion-between-louys-patrice-bessette-and-paulo-dos-santos).

Answer (score 0):

I have not run this code, but this logic should work.

In your HTML(Roughly):

```
    <div class="question" id="YOUR_QUESTION_ID">
        <p>
                Your question goes here..
        </p>
        <div class="options">
            <label><input type="radio" name="option_1"> Your option 1</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="option_2"> Your option 2</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="option_3"> Your option 3</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="option_4"> Your option 4</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Jquery:

```
    Use the latest version of JQuery.
```

In your JavaScript:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        if (typeof(Storage) == "undefined")  
        {
            alert("Your browser doesn't support Webstorage"); //Check browser support.
        }


        for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i))); // Log all previously stored values. These are the values what you want.
        }


        $("input[type='radio']").on("click",(function() //Set a click listener
        {
            var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id"); //There are two parents for this. Our goal is access the element with "YOUR_QUESTION_ID".
            var value = $(this).val();
            // Use the same id name as the key to store the values.
            localStorage.setItem(id,value);
            //The new id/key will be inserted or the existing key value is updated.
        }));
    });
```